# java.io.IOException: Posted content type isn't multipart/form-data

Tags: java, jsp

I have written a jsp page  for uploading image using POST method by using `com.oreilly.servlet.multipart.MultipartParser` actually file is successfully uploading and post values also getting correctly but it is throwing a exception

```
java.io.IOException: Posted content type isn't multipart/form-data 
MultipartParser mp = null;
try{
 mp = new MultipartParser(request, 1*1024*1024); // 10MB
 }
 catch(Exception e){
 out.println("Exception1:"+e);
 }
while ((part = mp.readNextPart()) != null) {
        name = part.getName();
        if (part.isParam()) {
            ParamPart paramPart = (ParamPart) part;
            value = paramPart.getStringValue();
            if(name.equals("companyname") && value != null){                

            }

            if(name.equals("version") && value != null && name != null){

            }

        }
        else if (part.isFile()) {
            String getimagelogovalue="";
            FilePart filePart = (FilePart) part;
            String fileName = filePart.getFileName();
            if (fileName != null) {

            }
            else {}
            out.flush();
        }
    }
```

Comment: can u plz post some code and the error msg
also check whether you have mentioned enctype="multipart/form-data" as your form attribute
after you have mention enctype="multipart/form-data" kindly take the file attribute in a local variable and print PhotoFile.getBytes()

Comment: MultipartParser mp = null;
 try{
  mp = new MultipartParser(request, 1*1024*1024); // 10MB
  }
  catch(Exception e){
  out.println("Exception1:"+e);
  }

Comment: can u plz post ur form code , only post the form line and the line where u have used the file input tag
and also on your server side how do u handle the value of file input param

Comment: what type of exception is thrown, post your exception trace

Comment: java.io.IOException: Posted content type isn't multipart/form-data

Comment: @raju: Try using `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute in your form.

Answer (score 2):

You have:

```
mp = new MultipartParser(request, 1*1024*1024); // 10MB
```

but by my calculations that is actually only 1Mb. Is the image you are trying to upload actually too large? Try smaller images, fix your comment or fix your code.

Answer (score 2):

I think the code that you have written over here is the server side code, assuming that you are doing a post form JSP your code should look like following

```
<FORM action="http://server.com/cgi/handle"
       enctype="multipart/form-data"
       method="post">
   <P>
   What is your name? <INPUT type="text" name="submit-name"><BR>
   What files are you sending? <INPUT type="file" name="files"><BR>
   <INPUT type="submit" value="Send"> <INPUT type="reset">
 </FORM>
```

See the enctype attribute. Also can we see the client side(JSP) code?

The code snippet is taken from 
http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2

Answer (score 1):

I Just changed

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

to
**`ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data"`**

in form tag

The Exception is resolved , and the form tag is below

```
 <form method="POST"  name="form1"  action="1StudentDVerify.jsp" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data">


</form>
```